# Running an MVC application on Sharepoint site or Convert to an Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-addin, asp.net, mvc

So we have a new SharePoint 2013 intranet site and I have been tasked with migrating our existing MVC and ASP forms sites to it for a single sign on.

My first idea was to just host them as applications in IIS but I am having little success.  I have learned though that you can convert projects to Sharepoint Add-in projects.  But before I make those changes I just wanted to make sure it was the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hosting a .Net web application inside SharePoint farm or converting it to an Add-in is not a right solution to achieve Single Sign On capability. The right solution is to make both SharePoint and .Net sites to rely on same identity provider. If this is an intranet site, most common practice is to rely on ADFS as the Identity provider. See a similar thread [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26670/single-sign-on-between-sharepoint-and-net-site)